# ImportError: Pandas requires version '0.3.0' or newer of 's3fs'

Tags: python, pandas, aws, error-handling

I'm trying to read files from S3, using boto3, pandas, anaconda, but I have the following error:

```
ImportError: Pandas requires version '0.3.0' or newer of 's3fs' 
(version '0.1.6' currently installed).
```

How can I update the s3fs version?

This is my code:

```
import boto3 
import pandas as pd
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket= s3.Bucket('bucketname')
files = list(bucket.objects.all())
files
objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='bucketname/')
objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="Teste/")
file_list = []
for obj in objects:
df = pd.read_csv(f's3://bucketname/{obj.key}')
file_list.append(df)
final_df = pd.concat(file_list)
print (final_df.head(4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong here - you need to update the Python package.

**Steps:**

1. Open your terminal
2. Type the command:

   ```
   pip install s3fs --upgrade
   ```